# Preferences of varying height within a PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, preference

I have a custom class that extends Preference that I'm using in conjunction with a PreferenceActivity.

When I try to adjust the height in the layout my Preference is using (with a static layout_height or with wrap_content) it is always displayed in a uniform height cell in the Preference Activity - the same size that all of the "normal" preferences default to.

Is there a way present a given preference with a different layout_height.

I've looked at the API demos related to preferences and I'm not seeing anything that matches what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Looking on an Api level 9 device the preferences are not the same height, but sizes based on the content.  For api 7 devices I have had to make changed to cope with sumaries > 2 lines.  is this your issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override `getView(View, ViewGroup)` in your Preference. Then send `new LayoutParams` to the `getView()`. I tried it with a customized CheckBoxPreference. Works great.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams;


public class CustomCheckBoxPreference extends CheckBoxPreference {

public CustomCheckBoxPreference(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
        final int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public CustomCheckBoxPreference(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomCheckBoxPreference(final Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final View v = super.getView(convertView, parent);
    final int height = android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    final int width = 300;
    final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(height, width);
    v.setLayoutParams(params );
    return v;
}
```

}

Just be careful to use the correct LayoutParams for the View or you might get a class cast exception.

Comment: It works. However, you lose the subtle checkbox animation.

Answer (score -1):

This should help:

```
<!-- Application theme -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Min item height -->
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeight">10dp</item>
</style>
```

another styling attributes that can be overridden can be found here [preference item layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27027982/975886)

Original answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27027982/975886

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Mathias it's just to avoid duplication