# Change height of Preference items

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a PreferenceFragment subclass. I want each one of its items (Preferences and SwitchPreferences) to have a height of 120dp. How to do that?

Here is the related code:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        public SettingsFragment() {}
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.main);         
        }
}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <SwitchPreference android:key="app_main_switch"
                      android:title="@string/app_name"
                      android:defaultValue="true"/>
    <Preference android:title="@string/events_lowercase"
                android:dependency="app_main_switch">
        <intent android:targetPackage="hu.ppke.itk.marma.android.bead" 
                android:targetClass="hu.ppke.itk.marma.android.bead.EventList"/>
    </Preference>
    <Preference android:title="@string/filters_lowercase"
                android:dependency="app_main_switch">
        <intent android:targetPackage="hu.ppke.itk.marma.android.bead" 
                android:targetClass="hu.ppke.itk.marma.android.bead.FilterList"/>
    </Preference>
    <SwitchPreference android:dependency="app_main_switch"
                      android:key="learn_switch"
                      android:defaultValue="false"
                      android:title="@string/learning"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is how it looks like now:

[image]

So I want all four items of the list to have a height of 120dp. As you can see I'm not the one creating the ListView, it's created internally. I tried to retrieve it with

```
findViewById(android.R.id.list)
```

but iterating over its elements gives Preference objects which do not allow me to set the height.

Comment: Can you show us some code please? It would help identify and resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, try creating a custom Preference class extending SwitchPreference and using that in your preference.xml. see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I managed to do this:

I did need to subclass Preference but MattMatt's answer didn't work.

```
public class HigherPreference extends Preference {
    public HigherPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public HigherPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }   
    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        Resources res=getContext().getResources();
        View v=super.onCreateView(parent);
        v.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.rowheight)));
        return v;
    }
}
```

The layout XML goes like what he provided.

Comment: where's AbsListView from?

Comment: @Jacky [android.widget.abslistview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html)

Comment: Great, thanks, work like a charm! Hint for others: the `rowheight` goes into `res/values/dimens.xml`.

Comment: Did you notice that the switch animation is lost in this case?

Comment: Finally, after so many hours of searching, an answer that works.

Answer (score 6):

Just do it this way:

```
<!-- Application theme -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Min item height -->
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeight">10dp</item>
</style>
```

another styling attributes that can be overridden can be found here [preference item layout](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/preference.xml)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot try it right now because I don't do any Android development recently.

Comment: It's OK,  maybe someone find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a custom Preference class (you may have to do it for every type of Preference you are going to use/want height to be 120DP)

```
public class SwitchPref extends SwitchPreference {

Context context;

public Pref(Context context) {
    super(context);

    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dpToPx(120));

    layout.setLayoutParams(params1);

       //if this returns just the linearlayout, you will have to add your own switch
       // or reference to a layout.xml resource

    return super.onCreateView(layout);

}

public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    int valueInDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.getResources()
                    .getDisplayMetrics());
    return valueInDp;
}

}
```

**Then, in your preference.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--use your custom SwitchPrefence class-->
    <my.package.name.SwitchPref android:key="app_main_switch"
                  android:title="@string/app_name"
                  android:defaultValue="true"/>
    <Preference android:title="@string/events_lowercase"
            android:dependency="app_main_switch">
        <intent android:targetPackage="hu.ppke.itk.marma.android.bead" 
            android:targetClass="hu.ppke.itk.marma.android.bead.EventList"/>
    </Preference>
    <Preference android:title="@string/filters_lowercase"
            android:dependency="app_main_switch">
        <intent android:targetPackage="hu.ppke.itk.marma.android.bead" 
            android:targetClass="hu.ppke.itk.marma.android.bead.FilterList"/>
    </Preference>
    <my.package.name.SwitchPref android:dependency="app_main_switch"
                  android:key="learn_switch"
                  android:defaultValue="false"
                  android:title="@string/learning"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Hope this helps, happy coding!